# how to get each values from a list of values in dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I want this `[9.623322512197774e-06, 0.0003608197148423642, 0.9478542804718018, 5.152213998371735e-05, 0.05172383785247803]` data from the printed output listed below. And also print the position and maximum value from the data, as for example here is 0.9478542804718018, at position 2.

```
{'fields': ['prediction', 'prediction_classes', 'probability'], 'values': [[[9.623322512197774e-06, 0.0003608197148423642, 0.9478542804718018, 5.152213998371735e-05, 0.05172383785247803], 2, [9.623322512197774e-06, 0.0003608197148423642, 0.9478542804718018, 5.152213998371735e-05, 0.05172383785247803]]]}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the list of values

```
v = d['values'][0][0]
```

To get the max value in the list

```
max(v)
```

To get the index of the max value

```
v.index(max(v))
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. You are awesome.

Comment: Feel free to accept it as the answer if it solved your problem!